# How to sum columns in WQL?

Tags: wmi, wmi-query

I want to calculate total and free disk space available on machine using WMI. and query for that is => select Size,FreeSpace from Win32_LogicalDisk.

this query returns multiple rows as machine has more that one drive. If I sum this columns then I will get expected result. I can easily achieve this in sql by query

SELECT sum(Size), sum(FreeSpace) FROM Win32_LogicalDisk

but it gives error for wql.

How can I achieve same in wql?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`WQL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394606%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) language has not support for the SUM function, because is only a subset of the SQL language, in order to get the total you must iterate over the instances and calculate the value yourself.